# Hibernate.INTEGER is unavailable, when the Hibernate version is upgraded to 4.2.0.CR1

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, compiler-errors

I have just upgraded Hibernate from 3.2.5 to [4.2.0.CR1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate4/4.2.0.CR1/hibernate-release-4.2.0.CR1.zip/download). I was using something like the following methods in DAO classes to locate the current row number in Oracle 10g with the `createSQLQuery()` method.

```sql
SELECT row_num
FROM   (SELECT row_number()
                 OVER (
                   ORDER BY banner_id DESC) AS row_num,
               banner_id
        FROM   banner_images
        ORDER  BY banner_id DESC)
WHERE  banner_id = :id
```

```java
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")    
public int getCurrentRow(String id, int rowsPerPage)
{        
    return (Integer) sessionFactory
                    .getCurrentSession()
                    .createSQLQuery("Above query")
                    .addScalar("row_num", Hibernate.INTEGER)  //<------- ???
                    .setParameter("id", Long.parseLong(id))
                    .uniqueResult();
}
```

The `.addScalar("row_num", Hibernate.INTEGER)` method as shown in the above code snippet, issues a compile-time error.

```
cannot find symbol
symbol:   variable INTEGER
location: class Hibernate
```

It is not available in the `org.hibernate.Hibernate` class. The NetBeans IDE I'm using is 7.2.1 is not listing such a constant. Google search couldn't lead me to the actual solution. So what is the alternative in this version of Hibernate (4.2.0.CR1)?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This Hinernate.Integer is deprecated since 3.6.x

You should use `IntegerType.INSTANCE` instead.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using an older version of Hibernate, but don't want to use a deprecated value while on 3.5.x or below, you'll have to use `new IntegerType()` because `IntegerType.INSTANCE` doesn't exist before 3.6.

Answer (score 3):

Do:

- import org.hibernate.type.StandardBasicTypes;
- replace Hibernate.INTEGER by StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER.